# How to install specific version clang 14.0.0？

Tags: clang, llvm

I use following steps install clang 14 success!But the version is 14.0.6.I want to install version 14.0.0.How do i do it？

```
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
./llvm.sh 14
```